# Custom CSS Cursor is Pixelated

Tags: html, css, cursor, photoshop

I'm playing around with custom cursors but every time I try it, it comes out pixelated, I made a ring asset to show how bad it is.

[Here is the cursor image file.](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/272259/circle.png)

```
cursor: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/272259/circle.png), auto;
```

It's 22px x 22px, about the size of the default cursor, but it renders really jagged.

Here's a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/041ec06b4e01115b059be6be5bb4daa4?editors=1100) to illustrate the bug.

Any ideas?

Thank you,

:)

Comment: Which browser? Because in Chrome it renders just fine..

Comment: Looks fine for me in Chrome 57.

Comment: @Goombah I just updated and it's still jagged, if you lean can you count pixels? I still can

Comment: @K48 same issue after update

Comment: looking perfect on chrome

Comment: @hunzaboy dang, maybe it's my hardware - what are you using

Comment: windows 7, chrome 54, i5

Comment: @hunzaboy thank you

Comment: iMac - Sierra - Chrome 54 here..

Comment: Tested on Chrome 54 on remote Windows 2008 server, now I do see the jagged circle..

Comment: @Goombah weird right?

Comment: @kathrynm Very weird. Tried an SVG, same result. Tried it as data-uri, same result. Can't find anything on the issue.

Comment: @Goombah thanks for trying :/

Answer (score 2):

In both IE and Edge only `.cur` files are supported, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358795(v=vs.85).aspx. (Edge supports other formats but not the interaction point definition.) The .cur file allows you to define the interaction point. Just google for ".cur editor" and choose the editor that suits you to create a .cur file.